# What is the meaning of arr[:] in assignment in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I occasionally use `numpy`, and I'm trying to become smarter about how I vectorize operations. I'm reading some code and trying to understand the semantics of the following:

```
arr_1[:] = arr_2
```

In this case,

I understand that in `arr[:, 0]`, we're selecting the first column of the array, but I'm confused about what the difference is between `arr_1[:] = arr_2` and `arr_1 = arr_2`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your question involves a mix of basic Python syntax, and `numpy` specific details.  In many ways it is the same for lists, but not exactly.

`arr[:, 0]` returns the 1st column of `arr` (a view), `arr[:,0]=10` sets the values of that column to 10.

`arr[:]` returns `arr` (`alist[:]` returns a copy of a list).  `arr[:]=arr2` performs an inplace replacement; changing the values of `arr` to the values of `arr2`.  The values of `arr2` will be broadcasted and copied as needed.

`arr=arr2` sets the object that the `arr` variable is pointing to.  Now `arr` and `arr2` point to the same thing (whether array, list or anything else).

`arr[...]=arr2` also works when copying all the data

Play about with these actions in an interactive session.  Try variations in the shape of `arr2` to see how values get broadcasted.  Also check `id(arr)` to see the object that the variable points to.  And `arr.__array_interface__` to see the data buffer of the array.  That helps you distinguish views from copies.

Answer (score 10):

`arr_1[:] = ...` changes the *elements* of the existing list object that `arr_1` refers to.

`arr_1 = ...` makes the name `arr_1` refer to a *different list object*.

The main difference is what happens if some *other* name also referred to the original list object. If that's the case, then the former updates the thing that both names refer to; while the latter changes what one name refers to while leaving the other referring to the original thing.

```
>>> a = [0]
>>> b = a
>>> a[:] = [1]
>>> print(b)
[1]                 <--- note, change reflected by a and b
>>> a = [2]
>>> print(b)
[1]                 <--- but now a points at something else, so no change to b
```

Comment: The question is about `numpy` arrays, not a list, though the idea is the same - changing elements versus changing the variable pointer.  `arr[:,0]` is not valid for a list.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it is best to understand by using `id` to examine the memory location of each variable.

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
arr2 = np.array([4, 5, 6])

>>> id(arr1)
4595568512

>>> id(arr2)
4595566192

# Slice assignment
arr1[:] = arr2

>>> arr1
array([4, 5, 6])

>>> id(arr1)  # The object still points to the same memory location of `arr1`.
4595568512

# Reassignment.
arr1 = arr2

>>> id(arr1)  # The object is now pointing to the object located to where `arr2` points.
4595566192
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `arr_1[:] = arr_2` is a shortcut for `arr_1.__setitem__(slice(None, None), arr_2)`.  The reason that is used instead of `arr_1 = arr_2` is when you use `__setitem__`, you are modifying `arr_1`, whereas when you say `arr_1 = arr_2`, you are redefining `arr_1`.  Using `__setitem__`, therefore, will modify other references to the `arr_1` object rather than just redefining `arr_1`.