# What is the difference between arr and arr[:] in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

i want to know the difference between list variable itself and listvariable followed by [:]

for example,

```
# When nums are List[int] and res are List,
# what is the difference between
res.append(nums[:])
# and 
res.append(nums)
```

my question came up while i'm implementing recursive permutation function

```py
class Solution:
    def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        res = []
        self.helper(nums, 0, len(nums) - 1, res)
        return res

    def helper(self, nums, l, r, res):
        if l == r:
            res.append(nums[:]) # this will append unique combination
            res.append(nums) # this will result in a list full of same combinations
        else:
            for i in range(l, r + 1):
                nums[l], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[l]
                self.helper(nums, l + 1, r, res)
                nums[l], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[l]
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Go through this, same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713891/what-is-the-meaning-of-arr-in-assignment-in-numpy and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440826/difference-between-arr-and-arr-in-python3-x

Comment: Generally speaking, `nums[:]` is equivalent to `nums.copy()`, which is what you should use nowadays if it's the behaviour you actually want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`nums[:]` is a convenient way to make a shallow copy of a list in python. `res.append(nums)` appends a reference to `nums`, ie any changes to `nums` will also be reflected in `res`. `res.append(nums[:])` will create a new copy of `nums` which you can change all you want without changing the original copy of `nums`

Hopefully this example makes it clear

```
nums = [1, 2, 3]
res = [nums]
res[0][0] = 'banana'
print(nums)

nums = [1, 2, 3]
res = [nums[:]]
res[0][0] = 'banana'
print(nums)
```

Gives the output

> ['banana', 2, 3]
>   [1, 2, 3]

Comment: It makes a shallow copy, not a deep copy.

Comment: @kaya3, edited, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`arr` alone copies the pointer to the original list, whereas `arr[:]` creates a copy of `arr`.

When we make changes to the original array, the changes are reflected in the pointer, but not the copy:

```
>>> foo = [1, 2, 3]
>>> pointer = foo
>>> acopy = foo[:]
>>> foo[0] = 'banana'
>>> foo
['banana', 2, 3]
>>> pointer
['banana', 2, 3]
>>> acopy
[1, 2, 3]
```

If we make changes to the pointer, the changes are reflected in the original but not the copy:

```
>>> pointer[0] = 'chocolate'
>>> foo
['chocolate', 2, 3]
>>> pointer
['chocolate', 2, 3]
>>> acopy
[1, 2, 3]
```

If we make changes to the copy, the changes are isolated from the original and the pointer:

```
>>> acopy[0] = 'monkey'
>>> acopy
['monkey', 2, 3]
>>> foo
['chocolate', 2, 3]
>>> pointer
['chocolate', 2, 3]
```